# Construct the Mikhailov hodograph for the equation $f(z)=z^3+z^2+z+2$.

Tags: complex-analysis, control-theory

Construct the **Mikhailov hodograph** for the equation $$f(z)=z^3+z^2+z+2$$

**Here's my solution:**

- We have $$f(i\omega)=(-\omega^2+2)+i(-\omega^3+\omega)$$.
- We consider $Ref(i \omega)=0$ and $Re \omega >0 \implies \omega_2=\sqrt{2}$
- We consider $Imf(i \omega)=0$ and $Re \omega >0 \implies \omega_0=0, \omega_1=1$.
- Whence, $f(i\omega_0)=2$, $f(i\omega_1)=1$, $f(i\omega_2)=-i\omega_2$

1/ Now, I have trouble when I construct the **Mikhailov hodograph** (starts on the positive real semi-axis, does not hit the origin and successively generates an **anti-clockwise** motion through $n$ quadrants.

(An equivalent condition is: The radius vector $f(i \omega)$, as $\omega$ increases from $0 $ to $+\infty$ , never vanishes and monotonically rotates in a positive direction through an angle $\dfrac{n\pi}{2}$), anyone can describes a curve? Thanks!

2/ I'm trying to find $\phi$ from $\phi=\dfrac{\pi}{2}(n-2m);n=3$. I have a question $\phi=?$. I mean **How** we can find $\phi$? Why? Thanks!

Comment: The radius vector $f(i\omega)$ does not monotonically rotate in a positive direction, because $f(0) = 2$ and $f(i)=1$.

Comment: Thanks **njguliyev**! What about $\phi$, how we can find $\phi=?$

Comment: I don't understand your second question. What is $m$?

Comment: @ **njguliyev** : $m$ is the number of solutions the equation $f(z) = 0$, with positive real parts ($Rez_j>0$).

Comment: Can you read **p.9**: http://books.google.com.vn/books?id=nSw5op5hblEC&pg=PA8&lpg=PA8&dq=Mikhailov+hodograph&source=bl&ots=4_N4cwfTpS&sig=GZLP5Okecj9igH1BcXx17BWYW74&hl=vi&sa=X&ei=Jyg_UtCvMqXeigfcl4GYDw&ved=0CGQQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q&f=true

Comment: In your case $m=2$, $n=3$. So $\frac{\pi}{2}(n-2m) = -\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: No no, The first, we must find $\phi$, implies $m$. Of course $\phi=-\pi /2$. But Why?

Comment: I mean we Construct the Mikhailov hodograph (drawing the curves), next, since the curvers (Mikhailov hodograph) implies $\phi$.

Comment: The Mikhailov hodograph: http://img10.picoodle.com/i59m/kimtahe6/s792_9ca_udizb.jpg. But I don't understand Why $\phi=-\pi/2$

Comment: $\operatorname{Arg} f(i\omega) \to -\frac{\pi}{2}$, $\omega \to \infty$. Because $\lim_{\omega \to +\infty} \dfrac{-\omega^3+\omega}{-\omega^2+2} = + \infty$.

Comment: I have an example: $$f(z)=z^4+z^3+4z^2+2z+2$$, then $$f(i \omega)=(\omega^4-4\omega^2+2)+i(-\omega^3+2\omega)$$. You mean $$\lim_{\omega \to +\infty} \dfrac{-\omega^3+2\omega}{\omega^4-4\omega^2+2} = 0$$. Hence, $\phi=?$ **njguliyev**.

Comment: In this case $\phi(\omega) \to 2\pi.$ To understand why, just look at the graph of $f(i\omega)$ and try to visualize what happens at infinity.

Comment: Yes, your result is correct $\phi = 2\pi$. Here's The Mikhailov hodograph for $f(z)=z^4+z^3+4z^2+2z+2$: http://g10.picoodle.com/ltd/img10/5/9/23/kimtahe6/f_t0gb_510_udizb.jpg Can you explain why since $\lim_{\omega \to +\infty} \dfrac{-\omega^3+2\omega}{\omega^4-4\omega^2+2} = 0$ and The Mikhailov hodograph (my picture) we have $\phi=2\pi$, please!

Comment: I have an example: $$f(z)=z^2+bz+c; b,c \in \mathbb{R}$$ then $$f(i \omega)=(-\omega^2+c)+i\omega b$$. Thus $$\lim_{\omega \to +\infty}\dfrac{\omega b}{-\omega^2+c}=0$$. Hence $\phi=?$

Comment: As you can see from your picture, the point $f(i\omega)$ starts at a point in the real line, goes to the first, then the second, then the third and then the fourth quadrant and stays there (because $\Re f(i\omega) = \omega^4-4\omega^2+2 >0$ and $\Im f(i\omega) = -\omega^3+2\omega <0$ for sufficiently large $\omega$). When $\omega \to \infty$ the fact that limit in your last comment goes to $0$ means that $f(i\omega)$ approaches the real line from the fourth quadrant, so $\varphi(\omega) = \operatorname{Arg}f(i\omega) \to 2 \pi$.

Comment: Thanks **njguliyev** What about $f(z)=z^2+bz+c; b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $\phi=?$ when I don't draw The Mikhailov hodograph? Please!

Comment: I mean I don't find The Mikhailov hodograph for $f(z)=z^2+bz+c; b,c \in \mathbb{R}$(I have no solution) then you can draw it (or you describe), then $\phi=?$